# How to do a right-click on Nautilus if it is on list view?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus

Not having a blank space to do a right-click:

[image: Not having a blank space to do a right-click]

Comment: In Nemo you can right-click on the whitespace that's not immediately by text, but it doesn't seem like Nautilus does that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a file/folder selected in list view, unselect it first by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open the context menu (right-click menu).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Menu Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) to emulate right click, which is usually on the right side between alt and ctrl. However, for it to work, you need to make sure none of the items are selected (like `/etc` in the screenshot above). To get rid of the selection, try switching to a different location, for example, Trash or Recent, and then back to where you need to be.

[image]